# C and Go interoperability issue involving C.free()

Tags: c, go, language-interoperability

I've a Go function that wraps the `proc_name(pid,...)` function from `lib_proc.h`.

This is the complete **C prototype**:

```
int proc_name(int pid, void * buffer, uint32_t buffersize) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

that can be found here `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/libproc.h` (at least on my system).

It follows Go code:

```
package goproc

    /*
    #include "libproc.h"

    int call_proc_name(int pid, char *name, int name_size) {
      return proc_name(pid, name, name_size);
    }
    */
    import "C"
    import "unsafe"
    import "strings"

    type DarwinProcess struct {
        Process
    }

    func (DarwinProcess) NameOf(pid int) string {
        name := C.CString(strings.Repeat("\x00", 1024))
        defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(name))
        nameLen := C.call_proc_name(C.int(pid), name, C.int(1024))
        var result string

        if (nameLen > 0) {
            result = C.GoString(name);
        } else {
            result = ""
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This code won't compile unless the call to `C.free(unsafe.Pointer(...))` and `import "unsafe"` clause are removed.
`DarwinProcess::NameOf(pid)` method is meant to work only on **Mac OS X** and *it actually works* if `C.free(...)` is removed from code.

In its actual form after `go build` I get the following error message:
`could not determine kind of name for C.free` (and nothing more, this is the whole compiler output).

Removing `C.free(...)` is not acceptable to me, I must find how to properly free the memory allocated with `C.CString()`.

I'm puzzled since, according to [documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/), everything is done properly. I have not been able to find a solution nor searching here nor on the web.

Comment: Have you tried adding `#include <stdlib.h>` in your cgo comment?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`libproc.h` doesn't include `stdlib.h`, where `free()` is declared. As such, the compiler cannot resolve the name. After I added `#include <stdlib.h>` at the beginning of the cgo comment block your code built successfully on my system.

Comment: +1 This worked perfectly and answers my question. To be honest I was misled by documentation that seems suggest that `C.free()` is part of the special `C` package. But in reality we're talking of standard `stdlib::free()`.

Comment: Like other runtimes also Go libs lack an API for managing already running OS processes, so I'm trying to writing one. For now just a stub (https://github.com/gsscoder/goproc).