# Forced to define Go struct for casting an unsafe.Pointer() to a C struct

Tags: c, pointers, go, language-interoperability

Interoperating with C code, I was not able to directly cast a structure and I was forced to define an equivalent one in Go.
The C function from `libproc.h` is

```
int proc_pidinfo(int pid, int flavor, uint64_t arg,  void *buffer, int buffersize)
```

The C structure for `flavor==PROC_PIDTASKINFO` is `proc_taskinfo` as defined in `sys/proc_info.h` (included by `libproc.h`):

```
struct proc_taskinfo {
    uint64_t        pti_virtual_size;   /* virtual memory size (bytes) */
    uint64_t        pti_resident_size;  /* resident memory size (bytes) */
    uint64_t        pti_total_user;     /* total time */
    uint64_t        pti_total_system;
    uint64_t        pti_threads_user;   /* existing threads only */
    uint64_t        pti_threads_system;
    int32_t         pti_policy;     /* default policy for new threads */
    int32_t         pti_faults;     /* number of page faults */
    int32_t         pti_pageins;        /* number of actual pageins */
    int32_t         pti_cow_faults;     /* number of copy-on-write faults */
    int32_t         pti_messages_sent;  /* number of messages sent */
    int32_t         pti_messages_received;  /* number of messages received */
    int32_t         pti_syscalls_mach;  /* number of mach system calls */
    int32_t         pti_syscalls_unix;  /* number of unix system calls */
    int32_t         pti_csw;            /* number of context switches */
    int32_t         pti_threadnum;      /* number of threads in the task */
    int32_t         pti_numrunning;     /* number of running threads */
    int32_t         pti_priority;       /* task priority*/
};
```

Even if Go code actually works, I was not able to use `C.proc_taskinfo` directly. The Go function is `propertiesOf()`: complete source [here](https://gist.github.com/gsscoder/0b6c46a4f5971c22c136).

If I reference the C structure, I got a similar error reported as in my [latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481268/c-and-go-interoperability-issue-involving-c-free) on the subject: `could not determine kind of name for C.proc_taskinfo`, but this time I'm sure the definition is imported with `#include`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)

> To access a struct, union, or enum type directly, prefix it with struct_, union_, or enum_, as in C.struct_stat.

Use `C.struct_proc_taskinfo`.

Comment: +1 This answers my question and gave me a better understanding of C/Go interoperability. I think this is in the documentation (which I consult), but an important thing like this should have appeared more clearly (with a lot of bold sentences...).

Comment: Change applied (it builds and passes tests), if anyone is interested in full (learning) project source, is possible to follow this [link](https://goo.gl/he4bPH).